# Error perisiting manyToOne relationship that can be null (org.hibernate.TransientObjectException)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence

i'm getting exception when i try to persist object Municipio. 
Municipio has manyTone Relationship to Provincia and another manyToOne relationship to Sector.
Provincia can't be null but Sector can be null. I don't know how to allow that Sector can be null because when I try to save object Municipio an Exception is thrown.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: es.caib.biocides.persistence.Municipio.sector -> es.caib.biocides.persistence.Sector
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:611)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$1.beforeCompletion(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:513)
```

Municipio

```
/**
* The persistent class for the BCD_MUNICIPIO database table.
* 
*/
@Entity
@Table(name="BCD_MUNICIPIO")
public class Municipio implements Serializable {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="BCD_MUNICIPIO_MUNCODIGO_GENERATOR", sequenceName="BCD_MUN_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="BCD_MUNICIPIO_MUNCODIGO_GENERATOR")
@Column(name="MUN_CODIGO")
private Long munCodigo;

@Column(name="MUN_NOMBRE")
private String munNombre;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Provincia
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="MUN_CODPRV")
private Provincia provincia;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Sector
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
@JoinColumn(name="MUN_CODSEC", nullable=true)
private Sector sector;

public Municipio() {
}

public Long getMunCodigo() {
    return this.munCodigo;
}

public void setMunCodigo(Long munCodigo) {
    this.munCodigo = munCodigo;
}

public String getMunNombre() {
    return this.munNombre;
}

public void setMunNombre(String munNombre) {
    this.munNombre = munNombre;
}

public Provincia getProvincia() {
    return this.provincia;
}

public void setProvincia(Provincia provincia) {
    this.provincia = provincia;
}

public Sector getSector() {
    return this.sector;
}

public void setSector(Sector sector) {
    this.sector = sector;
}

}
```

Sector

```
/**
* The persistent class for the BCD_SECTOR database table.
* 
*/
@Entity
@Table(name="BCD_SECTOR")
public class Sector implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="BCD_SECTOR_SECCODIGO_GENERATOR", sequenceName="BCD_SEC_SEQ")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="BCD_SECTOR_SECCODIGO_GENERATOR")
@Column(name="SEC_CODIGO")
private Long secCodigo;

@Column(name="SEC_NOMBRE")
private String secNombre;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to Municipio
@OneToMany(mappedBy="sector")
private List<Municipio> municipios;

public Sector() {
}

public Long getSecCodigo() {
    return this.secCodigo;
}

public void setSecCodigo(Long secCodigo) {
    this.secCodigo = secCodigo;
}

public String getSecNombre() {
    return this.secNombre;
}

public void setSecNombre(String secNombre) {
    this.secNombre = secNombre;
}

public List<Municipio> getMunicipios() {
    return this.municipios;
}

public void setMunicipios(List<Municipio> municipios) {
    this.municipios = municipios;
}


}
```

Comment: show ur save/modify code

Comment: The problem is with transient state not the `null` I think.

Comment: how did you resolve the problem with null `sector`?

Answer (score 2):

The TransientObjectException comes whenever you try to save the Object without saving the appropriate Joins.You have to save the **Sector** first and afterwards you can save your **Municipio** class.

```
Municipio.setSector(new Sector());
```

By using this you are assigning particular **Sector** to **Municipio**. But **Sector** does not have any ID. How would both get mapped ? That is why the exception is coming.

For more details, please post your save/update code.

Hope it would help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to a null object per se, but to the structure of your actual entities regarding the `OneToMany` declaration.

If I'm not mistaken, you're trying to save a `Municipio` associated with a `Sector` without previously saving the `Sector`, aren't you?. What happens is that Hibernate needs to do the associated mapping between the `Municipio` and it's owning `Sector`, but if the latter is not persisted yet, there's no reference to create the association.

Try saving the `Sector` first, then the `Municipio` (you can make use of cascading if you want to).

Answer (score 0):

In Municipio try explicitly initializing the sector as null. And yes as Sajan asked show your save/modify code.